# Combining adjoining 2D polygons

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone know of an algorithm or toolkit for python3 which I can use to combine touching 2D polygons in one polygon? Where the polygon is defined in terms of the lines that define its outer and indeed inner boundaries (A donought, for example, has an inner boundary to define its hole).

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

In my case however I begin with equal sized squares (polygons) which I need to combine into larger polygons.

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: What's your data structure like? I have a feeling we can come up with an easy algorithm to do this.

Comment: A square might look like this: ((50.0, 10.0), (50.001, 10.0), (50.001, 10.001), (50.0, 10.001))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like the General Polygon Clipper library might do what you're looking for](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software//).

Comment: yep, gpc is the thing you are looking for. not perfect but it works.

Comment: Yeah, I've started looking at it and it seems to do what I what. Must test inner bounds however...

Answer (score 2):

I would say you can use GDAL, 
They also support Python 3.

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython

Comment: This suggestion helped me, thanks. Its especially helpful for maps.

Answer (score 1):

There is huge geometry library called [opencascade](http://opencascade.org) and its [python bindings](http://www.pythonocc.org/). I don't know if they support python3 but it seems to be working. Btw, C library is very bad documented and very unintuitive so if with python is same I would try to find something better (easier).